# Dynamically requiring multiple fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I have a situation where a client wants field requirements to dynamically change based on some selection in the form. More specifically I have the following fields:

> Country (dropdown), state (dropdown), address, city, zip code

What they want is the following logic:

```
if US selected as country
    state, address, city, zip all required
else if any other country selected
    address, city required but state and zip code not required
```

How can I dynamically set the IsRequired setting of DevExpress controls based on what is selected on the client side country picker?

Comment: post your HTML markup for those dropdowns pls.

Comment: Consider a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIf]` attribute or similar conditional validation attribute applied to the `state` and `zipcode` properties so you get client and server side validation

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the `DevExpress` side, but generally speaking, you have to forgo the builtin validation and do custom validation instead. For example, in your action, you would just need to do something like:

```
if (model.Country == "US")
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.State))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("State", "State is required");
    }

    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.ZipCode))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("ZipCode", "Zip Code is required");
    }
}

if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    ...
```

Then, you simply don't apply `[Required]` to those properties on your view model at all, and instead rely on this code to validate them. If the country is "US" then they will be required, otherwise not.

However, this is a bit of code smell, honestly, and it doesn't cover things like client-side validation. You're probably better off with something like a custom `RequiredIf` attribute. You can find tons of examples of that with a simple search, so I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score -1):

Use the same method with optional parameter

```
public void Method(address, city, state = null, zip = null)
{
    //...
}
```